# Json java сложная структура со словарем для десериализации

Tags: java, json, map

```
{
"criterias": [
{"lastName": "Иванов"},
{"productName": "Минеральная вода", "minTimes": 5},
{"minExpenses": 112, "maxExpenses": 4000},
{"badCustomers": 3}
]
}
```

Вот такая структура jsonа, таким я думаю должен быть класс:

```
public class Criterias {
  public Criterias(){}

  public String lastName;
  public Map<String,String> productProperties;
  public Map<String, Integer> costRange;
  public Integer badCustomers;
}
```

С помощью Jackson делаю вот так:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(jsonString);

Criterias criterias = mapper.readValue(reader, Criterias.class);
```

И в полях nullы естественно.
Как такую структуру, десериализовать. Пробовал добавить аннотации джексона не помогает

Comment: у вас же List<Criterias> должен быть, не? + там ещё одной обёртки не хватает с полем criterias.

Comment: То есть вот так? List<Criterias> criterias = (Criterias)mapper.readValue(reader, Criterias.class);

Comment: нее, смотрите у вас должен быть класс `class MyClass { List<Criterias> criterias; }`

Comment: потому что у вас структура `{ "criterias": []}`